# How can I set the value of a variable passed into a function?

Tags: php, html, function, scope

I am working on a page that allows the user to "upload" multiple files at once (they are stored locally in folders relative to their type).

My problem is that when I try to pass `$upFile1` and `$fileInfo1` to `writeResults()` to update `$fileInfo1` with information about `$upFile1`, the echoed result is empty.

I did some research and this appears to be a scoping issue, but I'm not sure about the best way to get around this having just started learning PHP last month.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**foo.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>

<html>
    <head>
        <title>File Upload</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form method="post" action="foo.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <p>
                <b>File 1:</b><br>
                <input type="file" name="upFile1"><br/>
                <br/>
                <b>File 2:</b><br>
                <input type="file" name="upFile2"><br/>
                <br/>
            </p>
            <p>
                <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Upload Files">
            </p>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

**foo.php**

```
<?php

$upFile1 = $_FILES['upFile1'];
$upFile2 = $_FILES['upFile2'];

$fileInfo1 = "";
$fileInfo2 = "";

// Check if directories exist before uploading files to them
if (!file_exists('./files/images')) mkdir('./files/images', 0777, true);
if (!file_exists('./files/text')) mkdir('./files/text', 0777, true);

// Copies the file from the source input to its corresponding folder
function copyTo($source) {
    if (($source['type'] == 'image/jpg') || ($source['type'] == 'image/png')) {
        @copy($source['tmp_name'], "./files/images/".$source['name']);
    }
    if ($source['type'] == 'text/plain') {
        @copy($source['tmp_name'], "./files/text/".$source['name']);
    }
}

// Outputs file data for input file to destination
function writeResults($source, $destination) {
    $destination .= "You sent: ";
    $destination .= $source['name'];
    $destination .= ", a ";
    $destination .= $source['size'];
    $destination .= "byte file with a mime type of ";
    $destination .= $source['type'];
    $destination .= ".";
    // echoing $destination outputs the correct information, however
    // $fileInfo1 and $fileInfo2 aren't affected at all.
}

// Check if both of the file uploads are not empty
if ((!empty($upFile1['name'])) || (!empty($upFile2['name']))) {
    // Check if the first file upload is not empty
    if (!empty($upFile1['name'])) {
        copyTo($upFile1);
        writeResults($upFile1, $fileInfo1);
    }
    // Check if the second file upload is not empty
    if (!empty($upFile2['name'])) {
        copyTo($upFile2);
        writeResults($upFile2, $fileInfo2);
    }
} else {
    die("No input files specified.");
}

?>

<!DOCTYPE HTML>

<html>
    <head>
        <title>File Upload</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p>
            <!-- This is empty -->
            <?php echo "$fileInfo1"; ?>
        </p>
        <p>
            <!-- This is empty -->
            <?php echo "$fileInfo2"; ?>
        </p>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: So, which function exactly are you talking about, what do you expect it to do, what does it do instead and why do you expect scope to be an issue?

Comment: I edited my OP to clarify my problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you are passing the values of `$fileInfo1` and `$fileInfo2` but they are empty. After that there is no relation between the `$destination` value and the fileininfo values.

Change your function to return the `$destination` value.

Change your `writeResults` command to `$fileInfo1 = writeResults($upFile1);`

Comment: Would you recommend the return method over passing variables by reference?

Comment: Yes you can better use the return value

Comment: It's cleaner, in my opinion.

Comment: Both methods work but returning the value makes the code clearer. At least to me.

Comment: Thanks a bunch. I find it imperative to stick to best practices, and this should help me with future function declarations.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `&` sign to [pass variables by reference](http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.pass.php)

```
function addOne(&$x) {
    $x = $x+1;
}
$a = 1;
addOne($a);
echo $a;//2
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function writeResults($source, &$destination) {
    $destination .= "You sent: ";
    $destination .= $source['name'];
    $destination .= ", a ";
    $destination .= $source['size'];
    $destination .= "byte file with a mime type of ";
    $destination .= $source['type'];
    $destination .= ".";
    // echoing $destination outputs the correct information, however
    // $fileInfo1 and $fileInfo2 aren't affected at all.
}
```

Adding `&` in front of `$destination` will pass the variable by reference, instead of by value. So modifications made in the function will apply to the variable passed, instead of a copy inside the function.